# Capture value in a variable using regEx and findText

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to capture the number 10.0006 from the line:

total time:                          10.0006s

which is one line in a text file. So far I have:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('removed url').getBody().editAsText();

//locate totalTime text
var regEx = "/(?<=total time: )([\d\.]+[\d])(?=s)/";
var totalTime = doc.findText(regEx).getElement().getText();

//display values in log
Logger.log(totalTime);
```

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String) capture groups are not supported with findText, are there any other ways to capture the pattern? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts about regular expressions. Reference [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Rubén, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do it with two steps

1. find needed element with `findText`.
2. use JavaScript's `match` with same regex to match needed group of characters.

---

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('removed url').getBody().editAsText();

// locate totalTime text
var regEx = "total time: ([0-9.]+)s";
var foundRange = doc.findText(regEx);

// if range is found
if (foundRange)
{
  // get related element ant it's text
  var foundText = foundRange.getElement().getText();
  // capture needed group of characters
  var totalTime = foundText.match(regEx)[1];

  //display values in log
  Logger.log(totalTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kos, I ended up using our suggestion with a few tweaks shown below:

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up going with, thanks @Kos for the help!

```
// locate totalTime text
    var findLine = "total time:";
    var foundRange = doc.findText(findLine);


// if range is found
if (foundRange)
{
  var regEx = /[\d\.]+[\d](?=s)/
  // get related element and it's text
  var foundText = foundRange.getElement().getText();
    Logger.log(foundText);
  // capture needed group of characters
  var totalTime = foundText.match(regEx);

  //display values in log
  Logger.log(totalTime);
}
```